# Toggling show/hide anchored divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, anchor

I have a list of Services with their respective descriptions, which I have linked to with anchor links.
The service details are hidden until I click on a service name. I am not being able to hide the previously clicked on services, they are overlapping.

This is a JSFiddle of what I have been able to put together so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/rdhn60mb/

```
$('#home-header .service-box li a').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).css('display', 'block');
});

/*

$("#home-header .service-box li a").click(function(){
    var $name = $(this).text();
    var $activebox = ($("#" + $name).length === 0) ;


    $("#home-header .service-details").not($activebox).hide();
    $("#home-header .service-details").not($activebox).removeClass('active');

    $activebox.toggle();
    $activebox.toggleClass('active');

});

*/
```

(The commented out code doesn't work, but it's close to what I'm trying to achieve).

Thank you all for helping me out!

Cintia

Answer (score 0):

See in your case it's overlapping, as you never close/hide them. So as JavaScript/JQuery runs line by line. We will first close/hide all of them `$('.service-details').hide();` onclick and then open/show only the current one.

**JQuery**

```
$('#home-header .service-box li a').click(function() {
    $('.service-details').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).css('display', 'block');
});
```

**UPDATE :**

[Fiddle : Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rdhn60mb/19/)

> **Note:** Here in demo i used `fadeIn()` so it has some smoothing effect. Also using anything else like `toggle()` is useless. As you are hiding all the `service-details` before showing so no need of `toggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with divy3993's answer but improve it slightly:

```
$('#home-header .service-box li a').click(function() {
    $('.service-details').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
});
```

The toggle is just a more efficient function in this case.

You can see the example in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/rdhn60mb/6/

Comment: Thanks guys! It's getting close. I also want to be able to click the same link and toggle so it closes.

Ideally, I also want to be able to click outside of the link (anywhere on the page) and have it close as well.

This is the new Fiddle with the additional functions that I put in. 
https://jsfiddle.net/dwxn7pfk/

What doesn't work is that when you click on the same link twice (to toggle open/close) the active class and open/close toggles don't work.

Answer (score 0):

To close the div again if the same link is clicked like you wanted.. simple wrap it in an if statment checking if the current active tab has the same id as the href value. If so don't run the show

```
//if the clicked a element's href is not the same as the active elements id
if( $(this).attr('href') != "#"+$(".active").attr( "id" ) ) {

     //remove the current active class
     $('.service-details').removeClass( "active" );

    //fade in the div
    $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();

    //add the class active to the div
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass( "active" );
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the edits and I also added a fadeout to make it less jumpy

https://jsfiddle.net/rdhn60mb/21/